# How to get only one result with postgres lag() function

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I have the following table which stores historical prices for stocks

```
 stock_id |  open  | close  |  high  |  low   |      timestamp
----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------------------
        2 |    338 |    330 |    338 |    330 | 2022-10-21 05:30:00
        2 |    341 |    338 |    341 |    338 | 2022-10-20 05:30:00
        2 | 340.05 |    340 |    341 |    340 | 2022-10-19 05:30:00
        2 |    357 |    340 |    357 |    340 | 2022-10-18 05:30:00
        2 |    358 |    358 |    358 |    358 | 2022-10-12 05:30:00
```

I want to get the 1 day change from the previous day by using values of last 2 record and window function `LAG()` so I came up with the following query

```
SELECT stock_id,
       close as last_price,
       timestamp::DATE,
       LAG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY stock_id
                        ORDER BY timestamp desc) AS one_day_change
FROM historical_prices WHERE stock_id = 2;
```

But this me all the change not just the latest record

```
stock_id | last_price | timestamp  | one_day_change
----------+------------+------------+----------------
        2 |        330 | 2022-10-21 |
        2 |        338 | 2022-10-20 |            330
        2 |        340 | 2022-10-19 |            338
```

What I want instead is this

```
stock_id | last_price | timestamp  | one_day_change
----------+------------+------------+----------------
       2 |        330 | 2022-10-21 |            338
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Maybe `LAG()` is not suitable for this usecase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A window function doesn't reduce the number of result rows like an aggregate function does. It just adds another column to the result set.

You should sort ascending by `timestamp`, so that `lag` means the previous day. Then add an outer query that only selects the row with the latest timestamp:

```
SELECT stock_id, last_price, timestamp, one_day_change
FROM (SELECT stock_id,
             close as last_price,
             timestamp::DATE AS timestamp,
             LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) AS one_day_change
      FROM historical_prices
      WHERE stock_id = 2) AS subq
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Limit to just the first (i.e., chronologically latest) result.

```
SELECT stock_id,
       close as last_price,
       timestamp::DATE,
       LAG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY stock_id
                        ORDER BY timestamp desc) AS one_day_change
FROM historical_prices
WHERE stock_id = 2
ORDER BY timestamp desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: If you sort `DESC`, you'd need 'lead', right?